# Grails config Locations not understanding it

Tags: grails

I am trying to set up my grails config locations but I am not sure what to put instead of userHome, I changed the app name to file_down which is what my app is called. So how does it work ?

```
 grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${file_down}-config.properties",
                             "classpath:${file_down}-config.groovy",
                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${file_down}-config.properties",
                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${file_down}-config.groovy"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and for maintaining default settings, you don't have to modify those statements; they will be resolved to their appropriate values when the app is running because that location needs to get to the ".grails" directory. If you want to see what the value is, add this statement in some controller or a gsp page (no println and quotes are needed then):

```
println "${System.properties.'user.home'}"
```

And that will tell you what the path resolves to, it would be something like *c:\Users\katkut* for example for a username being *katkut*. If you have your .grails folder in some other place then go ahead and put the absolute path as you wish instead, but, I hope you are maintaining the default installation settings.

One more thing. If *userHome* gives you null when you try to print it, just replace it with *user.home* as you see in the above statement, I believe they are the same, but the latter is accessible inside your .groovy and .gsp files.